# jQuery: Need to "refresh" a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am adapting the [Coverflow technique](http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/) to work with a div. The coverflow function (included as a js file in the head section) is [here](http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/ui.coverflow.js). When I dynamically add a DIV, it doesn't show up in the coverflow. I am wondering if there is a way to add a destroy function to this js file so that whenever a new div add is added, I can call the destroy method and then reinstantiate. Any suggestions on how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasted a lot of hours trying to come up with a good technique but finally this seems to work. If you're passing a div to the function like this:

`$("div.divname").coverflow({});`

Then, do this when you add a new DIV:

```
addDiv();
divBackup = $("div.divname")
$("div.divname").remove()
$("parentdiv").append(divBackup)
$("div.divname").coverflow({});
```

If anyone has a good suggestion, please feel free to add it. Until then, figured this would help someone facing the same problem.

**Why this works?**

When you remove and add the div, all the eventhandlers are destroyed as well. So, the next time you call the coverflow function, it reattaches to everything that is present. **Beware though! If you attached other handlers, they will be lost as well.** I know this is not the optimal solution but use it if you have no other option.